# Pass UISwitch State from One View Controller to Another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiswitch

I have a UISwith in a viewcontroller A. I want to pass the state of the UISwitch to viewcontroller B. I am using Objective C. This is the code I'm using in viewcontroller A:

```
if (![switchview isOn]) {
                NSLog(@"OFF");   
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ON");
                [comment setObject:@"YES" forKey:kESActivityPrivateKey];
            }
```

I need to save the value of the UISwitch in viewcontroller B.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is the `viewcontroller A` on top of `viewcontroller B`? If so, you can solve it with delegates

Comment: Which method are you using to go to viewcontroller B? Is it segue or you are presenting the viewcontroller?

Comment: Actually I'm opening a camera view on top of viewcontroller A which is a NSObject. Within the CaptureManager NSObject I need to access the current state of the UISwitch in viewcontroller A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to access another view controller's view hierarchy directly. You should treat another view controllers views (and a switch is a kind of view) as private.

Set an IBAction on your switch that points to the owning view controller. In that action save the sate of the switch to a property of your view controller.

You can then access the property from the other view controller.